# scrape hidden pages if search yields more results than displayed

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Some of the search queries entered under https://www.comparis.ch/carfinder/default would yield more than 1'000 results (shown dynamically on the search page). The results however only show a max of 100 pages with 10 results each so I'm trying to scrape the remaining data given a query that yields more than 1'000 results.
The code to scrape the IDs of the first 100 pages is (takes approx. 2 minutes to run through all 100 pages):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# as the max number of pages is limited to 100
number_of_pages = 100

# initiate empty dict
car_dict = {}

# parse every search results page and extract every car ID
for page in range(0, number_of_pages + 1, 1):
    newest_secondhand_cars = 'https://www.comparis.ch/carfinder/marktplatz/occasion'
    newest_secondhand_cars = requests.get(newest_secondhand_cars + str('?page=') + str(page))
    newest_secondhand_cars = newest_secondhand_cars.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(newest_secondhand_cars, "lxml")

    for car in list(soup.find('div', {'id': 'cf-result-list'}).find_all('h2')):
        car_id = int(car.decode().split('href="')[1].split('">')[0].split('/')[-1])
        car_dict[car_id] = {}
```

So I obviously tried just passing a `str(page)` greater than 100 which does not yield additional results.
How could I access the remaining results, if at all?

Comment: Sometimes these results are loaded with javascript in the browser, which means that you will have to work around that. Could you verify that is not happening by looking at the result in the browser.

Comment: the actual results on the page are in a div with id "result_list_ajax_container", this would indicate to me that they are loaded dynamically. What would be your guess on this?

Comment: I would agree. This seems to indicate that the result is loaded at client side when browsing. What you need is Scrapy-Splash. It act as a client that will render any javascript, and then you scrape from that client. If you know how to use docker that is possibly the easiest way to get started: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

Comment: use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript. It can be simpler then installing `Splash` which was created for [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your website loads data when the client is browsing. There are probably a number of ways to fix this. One option could be to utilize [Scrapy Splash](http://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).

Assuming you use scrapy, you can do the following:

1. Start a Splash server using docker - make a note of the
2. In `settings.py` add `SPLASH_URL = <splash-server-ip-address>`
3. In `settings.py` add to middlewares

this code:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
```

4. Import `from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest` in your spider.py
5. Set `start_url` in your spider.py to iterate over the pages

E.g. like this

```
base_url = 'https://www.comparis.ch/carfinder/marktplatz/occasion'
start_urls = [
     base_url + str('?page=') + str(page) % page for page in range(0,100)      
    ]
```

6. Redirect the url to the splash server by modifing `def start_requests(self):`

E.g. like this

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
            endpoint='render.html',
            args={'wait': 0.5},
        )
```

7. Parse the response like you do now.

Let me know how that works out for you.