# Different scraped webpage content between requests and aiohttp

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-asyncio

I am trying to speed up web scraping by removing blocking I/O, so I decided to change the requests package to aiohttp.

Unfortunately after switch to aiohttp, websites 
built with Angular give me the response without dynamic content.

So, I have the following 2 questions,

1. Why the requests module gives me proper (rendered) content if it
   doesn't run JS like selenium, but aiohttp not?
2. How can I fix the code to get proper content with aiohttp?

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import requests

URL = 'https://justjoin.it/'


async def fetch_async(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()


async def main():
    content_async = await fetch_async(URL)
    content_requests = requests.get(URL).text

    print('Are equal: ', content_async == content_requests)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Neither package will run any JS, can you inspect which headers are being sent to see if there is a difference?

Comment: AIOHTTP headers:```<CIMultiDictProxy('Host': 'justjoin.it', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.6.2')>```

Requests headers:  ```{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Iain suggested that I should invistigate headers send to server, after playing with headers I discovered that returned content depends on User-Agent.

When i send aiohttp request with 'USER-AGENT' :'python-requests/2.22.0' I got rendered content, same for 'Google Bot' but if User-Agent was set to 'Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.6.2' or 'Firefox' i got not rendered content.

So for some user-agents server makes server side rendering.

Solution:

```
async def fetch_async(url):
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0'}) as resp:
        print('AIOHTTP headers: ', dict(resp.request_info.headers))
        return await resp.text()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. JavaScript is a client side rendering of the website, which is what selenium simulates. With Selenium you start a webdriver that will load the acutal website and thus simulate an actual user. I expect that is where the problem is with aiohttp, that from the looks of your code is not running a webdriver, so JavaScript on the page will never be triggered and therefor never rendered.
2. I'm going to propose a different solution than using aiohttp, because your overall purpose is to improve the speed of scraping.

**Suggestion**
There is a module called **[Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)**, which will be able to help you scraping in parallel, follow links, scrape subpages and much much more that I can definitely recommend.

**Fixing load of JS pages**:
Whether you are using aiohttp or scrapy, you will need to simulate a user for JavaScript to be rendered. Here is (Hurray!) another module called **[Scrapy-Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)**. It involves a bit of configuration and the learning curve might seem a bit steep to start of with, however, it comes with everything you need when web scraping. For setting up Splash I've written another answer of this here [scrape hidden pages if search yields more results than displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575378/scrape-hidden-pages-if-search-yields-more-results-than-displayed/59577019#59577019). I recommend taking a look at that too.

Scrapy Splash can be utilized directly by aiohttp, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#why-not-use-the-splash-http-api-directly), however, there are a number of issues that is not handled that way that scrapy takes care of.

The following is an untested example of what your Spider in Scrapy might look like.

**Using Scrapy: Example Spider** *(Not tested)*

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class JustJoinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "justjoin"
    splash_args = {
        'html': 1,
        'png': 1,
        'width': 600,
        'render_all': 1,
        'wait': 0.5
    }
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://justjoin.it/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args=splash_args)

    def parse(self, response):
    # magic responses are turned ON by default,
    # so the result under 'html' key is available as response.body
    html = response.body

    # you can also query the html result as usual
    title = response.css('title').extract_first()
    company-name = response.css('company-name').extract_first()
    company-address = response.css('company-address').extract_first()

    # full decoded JSON data is available as response.data:
    png_bytes = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
```